# What am I doing wrong with read() and write()?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, unistd.h

I'm trying to do some beginner kernel module/user level program communications. I got the suggestion earlier to use `fdopen()` which worked well, but I've found out I'm required to use `open()`, `read()` and `write()` instead. I read the man pages for these and thought I converted the fopen,fgets,fputs to these correctly and my program compiles, but I'm not getting the desired output.

I have a timer where if I enter `./userprogram -s (int) (name)` e.g. `./userprogram -s 5 hello`, after 5 seconds it will print `hello` to the console by communicating with my kernel module. After I've switched to these new functions it instead prints `/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0` (and seems to wait ~5 seconds regardless now). Do I also need to change how my kernel level code works? I thought I'd just be able to change the user level program and the kernel module would continue to work as it did before. Here's what I tried wit the original code that worked commented out:

```
// open file
int pFile;
pFile = open("/dev/mytimer", O_RDWR);
if (pFile < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "mytimer module isn't loaded\n");
    return 1;
}

// Check if timer set
if (argc >= 4 && strcmp(argv[1], "-s") == 0) {
    lenNum = strlen(argv[2]);
    lenName = strlen(argv[3]);
    char *ptr = malloc(lenNum+lenName+4);
    strncat(ptr, argv[1], 2);//flag
    strncat(ptr," ", 1);
    strncat(ptr, argv[2], lenNum);//timer length
    strncat(ptr," ", 1);
    strncat(ptr, argv[3], lenName);//message

    /* fputs(ptr, pFile); */
    write(pFile, ptr, sizeof(ptr));
    /*
    while (fgets(line, 256, pFile) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    } */
    while (read(pFile, ptr, sizeof(ptr)) != 0) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You were already using `open()`, at least, if you were obtaining a stream via `fdopen()`.

Comment: I think I was doing something like `int file = open()` then `FILE *pFile = fdopen(file, "r+");` Then used `open()` on `file` and `fgets()` and `fputs()` on `pFile`.

Comment: `fdopen()` associates a stream with an open file descriptor.  You have to get the file descriptor somehow, and that would normally be via `open()`.  You could of course `fdopen()` one of the standard file numbers, but that's pointless because you already get `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` for free.

Comment: You did not not consider the length of `argv[1]` length when you allocated memory to copy it to. But worse is `strncat(ptr, argv[1], 2);` because `*ptr` is not an initilialsed string. `malloc` **does not initialise memory** it only allocates it.

Comment: You need to check the return codes from **write()** and **read()** (and all syscalls) for errors (and report them), especially since you're having issues.  BTW nice to see someone using K&R style for a change.

Comment: Why go to the trouble of concatenating a bunch of strings into a dynamically-allocated buffer, when you could instead just write each string and separator individually?

Comment: That was a piece of code I got from an example so I just went with it. I changed to using `asprintf()` though. For some reason no matter what I use I now get a`?` character on printing to console that comes before the `#` on the newline. Any idea why this might be? I figured it would have something to do with not using the proper size, but with `strlen()` I don't know why this would be an issue.

Comment: by the way this problem seems to only happen when for `-s (time) (name)`, `name` is four characters or less. If name is three characters it will print `??`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [I] thought I converted the fopen,fgets,fputs to these correctly

... but you were mistaken.  There is no one-line `write()`-based equivalent to `fputs()`, and no one-line `read()`-based equivalent to `fgets()`.  The stream-based I/O functions do a lot of work that you have to do yourself when you use low-level `read()`s and `write()`s.

Some of the differences are:

- `read()` does not supply string termination.  You have to do that yourself.
- `write()` does not pay attention to string termination.  If you want it to stop at string terminators then you have to control that via the number of bytes you ask it to transfer.
- `read()` and `write()` are neither one guaranteed to transfer the full number of bytes requested in one call.  If you want to transfer a specific number of bytes then you have to be prepared to loop.
- `read()` does not automatically stop at any particular character, including newline
- Most streams provide for buffering, invisibly to you.  If you want to buffer your `read()`s and `write()`s then you have to handle it yourself (but those functions are well suited for it).

In your particular case, however, you have also committed a semantic error.  The third argument to both `write()` and `read()` is the the maximum number of bytes to transfer -- often the size of the buffer -- but `sizeof(ptr)` is the size of your pointer itself, not the size of the space to which it points.

Comment: I thought I read that `fputs()` doesn't do termination but `puts()` does? I guess I might have read that wrong too.  I'm confused about your 3rd bullet point, could you explain this a little more? I changed `sizeof()` to `strlen()` as @Jens suggested and it seems to have fixed part of the problem, but I'm still getting some weird characters appended.

Comment: @Austin `puts()` outputs a newline after the string contents, and `fputs()` does not, but both pay attention to string termination.  Else, you couldn't talk about "string contents" in the first place.  The string terminator tells both of them where the contents end.  The `write()` function, on the other hand, makes no distinctions based on the values of the bytes you present to it.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(ptr)` is probably 4 or 8 (i.e. `sizeof(char *)`), not the length of the data you want to write.

And the way you construct the data is extremely cumbersome. Why not use a single `sprintf()`, or, if you have it, `asprintf()`, which even mallocs the memory:

```
char *ptr;
int i;

i = asprintf (&ptr, "%s %s %s", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
write (pFile, ptr, i);
free(ptr);
```

Ain't that sweet and concise?

Comment: @Austin It's an extension over ISO C and POSIX found on many Unix systems.

Comment: @Jens, it's sweet and concise, yes, but not wholly correct.  It does not account for the possibility of a short `write()`.  It doesn't do any error checking either, but in that respect it is parallel to the OP's attempt.

Comment: What's the issue when there's a short `write()`?

Comment: @Austin A short write means less than i bytes were written. A robust program would use the return value from write() and check if the write was short, then attempt to write the remaining bytes, until all bytes are written. Or it might just issue a warning about a short write. Usually short writes are rare, but there are circumstances like file systems being full, messages too long for a socket, where they occur.